# Confused with the use of assignment "=" and brackets { }

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am new to gradle (and so also to groovy) and I am hardly getting behind some concept and don't really know if it is groovy or gradle related and what keywords to google, to get some help.

I very often stumble over stuff like:

```
android {
    [some configuration]
}
```

So what is android? A class? A namespace? A collection of properties?

But what is more confusing:

Sometimes I see configurations that look like:

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

This seems to be an assignment, but without an equal sign.
And sometimes there are assignments with equal signs like

```
source = "folder/file.java"
```

So this is very confusing. Equal sign vs. no equal sign. All these bracket stuff.

All the groovy introductions I saw don't cover exactly these topics.
So is it some gradle convention or is it real groovy syntax?

Comment: Your question expresses exactly the confusion I have +1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Groovy, parentheses are sometimes optional.

The first `android` is passing a closure to a Method.  ie:

```
void android( Closure config ) {
    println "In Android : ${config()}"
}

android {
    'tim'
}
```

prints : `In Android : tim` it is the same as calling:

```
android( {
    'tim'
} )
```

If you put the parens back.

The second example with `minSdkVersion` is the same, but it is passing an Integer to a method.

```
void minSdkVersion( Integer version ) {
    println "In MinSdkVersion : $version"
}

minSdkVersion 19
// same as minSdkVersion( 19 )
```

So that prints `In MinSdkVersion : 19`

The last example is setting a property to a String (as you'd expect)

Comment: Many Gradle types have a method generated for each property so that one can write `minSdkVersion 19` instead of `minSdkVersion = 19`. `foo { prop1 = ...; prop2 = ...; ... }` is the syntax for configuring an object named `foo`. It's typically similar to but more succinct than `foo.prop1 = ...; foo.prop2 = ...; ...`. Knowing the type of `foo`, one can look up its methods and properties in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), or, in the case of an external plugin such as the Android plugin, in the plugin's documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot to get behind this concept.

Comment: Please note, that the syntax `<property> <value>` is not always the same as using the assignment operator `<property> = <value>`, which will always call the setter of the property. The auto-generated method is often used to add a new parameter to an existing set, while the setter may replace existing values. One example for this behavior is `onlyIf { ... }` / `onlyIf = { ... }` on Gradle tasks.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking `android` is a dynamic method that accepts a closure (a code block), that is given access to some internal representation of `android` plugin/task configuration. So, inside that closure you eventually either call other methods or do assignments to the properties that are available. If there is no equal sign then it is a method call, if there is then it is a pure property. You can get the idea by looking at plugin documentation or at the objects that represent it.

I think you can safely refer to this block as android plugin configuration. Since it is what the code affects.

Answer (score 1):

In gradle, you have plugins which each includes properties and methods for extension.

Properties are groovy properties and their getters/setters are [auto-generated](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html). And when you want to change a property what happens behind the scenes is calling it's generated setter. So, basically, it's a method call.

Method call can be done in various ways (just syntactic sugar). For example, you can omit [the paranthesis or commas](https://youtu.be/9S4AgFZsxcQ?t=18m13s). I think the link should explain the look you've mentioned.

How those methods and properties resolved is entirely different thing though. If you're interested in where those words come from, check delegates.