# Explain Gradle DSL magic for maven.url

Tags: gradle, groovy

I see:

```
repositories {
    maven.url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    maven.url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot'
}
```

and

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-release' }
    maven { url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot' }
}
```

both work.

[According to documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html) `MavenArtifactRepository` have property `url`.

What is following - a method call on `url` value or call of property setter:

```
 maven.url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-release'
```

What is following (I guess it's calling `MavenArtifactRepository` constructor):

```
 maven { url 'http://example.com/artifactory/libs-release' }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused with the use of assignment "=" and brackets { }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759542/confused-with-the-use-of-assignment-and-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets analyze the `url` property access (in both examples):

Is it a method call or a call of the property setter? Well, its kinda both. Let's quote [Mr. Hakis blog](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2016/02/gradle-goodness-methods-generated.html):

> Gradle will create a proxy class for the actual class implementation and adds (among other things) also a property setter method. The method has the name of the property and has a single argument of the same type as the property. It is different from the `setProperty` and `getProperty` methods already added by Groovy.

This is pure syntactic sugar, which supports the Gradle feeling of combining configuration and scripting. If you think it is misleading, simply use the assignment operator (which will also use the setter, thanks to Groovy).

Now, what about that `maven` part?

It looks like a property of `repositories`. But if we look at the definition of its type [`RepositoryHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html), we detect that it is a method creating a new [`MavenArtifactRepository`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/MavenArtifactRepository.html) accepting either a closure or an action (for Java usage) for configuration.

This simply explains the second example, as we pass a closure, which then configures the `url` property. Groovy allows to skip the brackets.

The first example is more tricky. We still use the same method, but this time we give an empty configuration closure as parameter. The method still returns a new `MavenArtifactRepository` and we access its `url` property.

Comment: I need 10 caps of coffee and one evening to understand this syntax magic.  Can you recommend reading on topic beside official docs? Something in http://www.mrhaki.com/books.html ?

Comment: Actually, I did not read any book, only the Gradle / Groovy documentation and several pages from searching Google (which often lead to Mr. Hakis Blog).